# add qty for similar json objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, nodes

I want the result to be summing all the qty of same cat.

```
        var  data = [
             { cat: 'EK-1',name:"test",info:"mat", quantity: 3},
             { cat: 'EK-2', name:"test2",info:"nat"quantity: 1}
              ];
```

I tried like this below i have array of object having some similar objects. how to add qty and create unque objects .below i have given  what i tried.

```js
var data = [{
    cat: 'EK-1',
    name: "test",
    info: "mat",
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    cat: 'EK-1',
    name: "test",
    info: "mat",
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    cat: 'EK-1',
    name: "test",
    info: "mat",
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    cat: 'EK-2',
    name: "test2",
    info: "nat",
    quantity: 1
  }
];

const products = Array.from(data.reduce((acc, {
    cat,
    quantity
  }) =>
  acc.set(cat, (acc.get(cat) || 0) + quantity),
  new Map()
), ([cat, quantity]) => ({
  cat,
  quantity
}));

console.log(products);
```

Comment: Have you tried [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

Comment: The property is called `quantity`, not `qty`, like you access in your reduce's destructuring.

Comment: i have updated my question ,,, but how can i get all keys and values in the result

Comment: var data = [{
    cat: 'EK-1',
    name: "test",
    info: "mat",
    quantity: 1
  }, {
    cat: 'EK-1',
    name: "test",
    info: "mat",
    quantity: 1
  }, {
    cat: 'EK-1',
    name: "test",
    info: "mat",
    quantity: 1
  }, {
    cat: 'EK-2',
    name: "test2",
    info: "nat",
    quantity: 1
  }]

const transform = (data) => 
    data.reduce((p, { cat, quantity }) => 
        (p[cat] = (p[cat] || 0) + quantity, p), {})

console.log(transform(data))

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), using the accumulator to pass on the new object:

```js
var data = [ { cat: "EK-1", name: "test", info: "mat", quantity: 1, }, { cat: "EK-1", name: "test", info: "mat", quantity: 1, }, { cat: "EK-1", name: "test", info: "mat", quantity: 1, }, { cat: "EK-2", name: "test2", info: "nat", quantity: 1, }, ];

let seen = [];
const res = data.reduce((acc, { cat, ...rest }) => {
  const idx = seen.indexOf(cat);
  if (idx == -1) (acc.push({cat, ...rest}), seen.push(cat));
  else acc[idx].quantity++;
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```